# Which value should I assign to OpenFileDialog.FileName?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

For this program, I want to know, what does FileName get? Document? or `d:\aa.doc`?
As my understanding, openfd.FileName can be `d:\\aa.doc` or `Document`.
But seems `Document` is not assigned, only `d:\\aa.doc` assignment works, why?

```
string FileName = "d:\\aa.doc";   //assign d:\aa.doc to Filename

private void openIt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openfd = new OpenFileDialog();
    openfd.FileName = "Document";  // not assign Document to FileName?
    openfd.DefaultExt = ".doc";  
    Nullable<bool> result = openfd.ShowDialog();

    if (result == true)
    {
        string filename = openfd.FileName;
```

Comment: Why assign anything to `FileName`? You would only do this if you want to pre-populate the filename field before the dialog is opened. Most everyone leaves it blank.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A bit more info here may help.

Comment: A repeat of a question you already asked and marked as answered.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465160/openfiledialog-filename-is-path-name-or-file-name#comment34172628_22465160  -1

Comment: Since my previous question was misleaded, so i have to post it again

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx), delving deeper into the [`FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) property - _Gets or sets a string containing the file name selected in the file dialog box._ , along with a complete working example program

Comment: Oops, that's for Winforms, here's the information for WPF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filename.aspx

Comment: this question makes no sense .... please be precise as to wha the question actually is or the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick primer on OpenFileDialog:

You almost never assign a value to FileName, as this value is the path to the file the user selected. You can use it to pre-populate the file name, but if the file doesn't exist in the start folder, it may well revert to String.Empty (the behavior you described). The first assignment you do has nothing to do with the file dialog, so of course it will always succeed.

What it looks like you are trying to do is set the filter string to word documents, which you do by setting the filter property like so:

```
openFd.Filter = "Word Documents|*.doc"
```

You can read more about the Open file dialog on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Please let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: Thanks! i have no idea why someone vote down this only and correct answer.

Comment: I'm not sure either. Thanks for your feedback!